# How serialization affects inheritence in Java?

Tags: java, serialization

first case:

```
class A 
{
    some methods
}

class B extends A implements Serializable
{
    some methods
}

class C
{
    B b=new B()
  // do some work
}
```

second case:

```
class A implements Serializable
{
    some methods
}

class B extends A
{
    some methods
}

class C
{
    B b=new B()
   // do some work
}
```

In first case, in class C we creating an object of class B  and  class A will be serialized ? And in second case class B is serialized or not? When we create an object of class B in class C?

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment you need to do yourself.

Comment: is anything wrong with that question?

Comment: Read here http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/11/inheritance-in-java-serialization_30.html
This might help you!

Comment: i have searched lot of resource and i messed up with resource, so i thought to ask here...

Answer (score 0):

> In 1st case, class B and A will be serialized

No. Only class B.

> but in 2nd case class B is serialized or not?

Of course, *and* class A.

A class is serialized if and only if it is declared as implementing `Serializable,` or an interface that extends `Serializable`, or as extending a class that does either.

You seem to have your question back to front from your code.

Comment: if follwoing scenerio comes

 in case 1:

class C
{
 A a=new A()
  //do some work
}

then what will happen? will class a will persist?